# Storing variables in file for later reuse

Tags: python, file, variables

I am able to access file path stored in a variable using sqlContext.read.parquet
where `var1 = "s3n://path1/path2/*/*snappy.parquet"` , below code works

```
def funname(date):

   pDF=sqlContext.read.parquet(var1)
```

But when I put this var1 = "s3n://path1/path2/*/*snappy.parquet" inside a file 'file1.dat' , i am not able to access this variable when using pDF=sqlContext.read.parquet(var1)

Error :

ERROR:global name 'var1' is not definednNone

Comment: And how do you expect the program to figure out that your `var1` is stored in a file?

Comment: How about reading the value of `var1` from file1.dat before using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible for you to "store" a variable in a text file and have python know of its existence. But you can store a path and later load it into your program.

---

Inside your file, store the path to your parquet and *nothing else*.

`file1.dat`

```
s3n://path1/path2/*/*snappy.parquet
```

Now, use python's file IO to read the file and store it in `var1`.

`your_file.py`

```
with open('file1.dat') as f:
    var1 = f.read().strip()

pDF = sqlContext.read.parquet(var1)
```